# When I try to start chrome I get a message that says "Failed to load extension from: .Manifest file is missing or unreadable"

Tags: google-chrome

All of a sudden when I try top open chrome on ubuntu, I get this message:
[image]

Then when I click OK it opens without my profiles.  I have now deleted all profiles, and uninstalled, purged, and reinstalled chrome and it keeps happening.

Anybody else having this problem?

chrome: Version 55.0.2883.87 unknown (64-bit)

ubuntu: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: When you reinstall Google Chrome, try deleting the `~/.config/google-chrome/` folder too before reinstalling.  All extensions for Chrome are stored in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/`.

Comment: yes I uninstalled, purged, deleted the `google-chrome` directory, reinstalled, started chrome from the command line, and then closed it and started it again and got the message again.

Comment: One other thing I can think of would be to check your extensions one-by-one from `chrome://extensions/` in the Chrome browser till you find the culprit that is not loading properly.

Comment: The problem is when chrome does open after the pop-up, it opens a completely different profile, without any extensions.  There are lots of extensions in the folder, but I guess they are the default ones because it is a new installation.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533661/chrome-says-my-extensions-manifest-file-is-missing-or-unreadable

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After finally fixed it by deleting all the `.desktop` entries for chrome.

```
find ~ -name "*chrome*.desktop"
#and then after looking at the list and maybe looking inside the files and deciding
#that you are ok with deleting them just to see if this fixes it....
find ~ -name "*chrome*.desktop" | xargs rm
#or something like
find ~ -name "*chrome*.desktop" | xargs gvfs-trash
#or maybe just save them in a folder or rename them while you make sure
#this is the problem
```

I can't reproduce the situation so I can't tell you for sure if this was it, but it might be worth a shot if you have the same problem.

Comment: I had that after running selenium locally. These instructions helped.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem as a result of an incompletely installed extension.  The extension, `chromium-lwn4chrome`, was installed through aptitude.  I've got no idea how some of its files ended up not being installed.

I finally found it by running

```
strace -ochromium.strace chromium
```

In the chromium.strace file, I searched for the string "anifest" and found the lines

```
 lstat("/usr/share/chromium/extensions/lwn4chrome", 0x7ffd0c3bc520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 access("manifest.json", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Searching for `lwn4chrome`, I found

```
 open("/etc/chromium.d/lwn4chrome", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

Investigating that file, I found

```
export CHROMIUM_FLAGS="$CHROMIUM_FLAGS --load-extension=/usr/share/chromium/extensions/lwn4chrome"
```

but there was no file or directory named `/usr/share/chromium/extensions/lwn4chrome` on my system.  I purged the `chromium-lwn4chrome` package, and the problem went away.  I then reinstalled it (because I was curious) and this time everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem.  This is how I fixed it:

```
apt-get remove google-chrome-stable
export CHROME_VERSION="google-chrome-stable"
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - 
echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
apt-get update -qqy
apt-get -qqy install ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable}
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*
```

Comment: I was wrong, start from console did the job...

Comment: This answer would be better if you annotated what each line does.

Comment: After performing these steps chrome started working.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it opening chrome and navigating to chrome://version/

It showed me the following:

**Chromium:**   71.0.3578.98 (Versão oficial) snap 64 bits
**Revisão:**    15234034d19b85dcd9a03b164ae89d04145d8368-refs/branch-heads/3578@{#897}
**SO:** Linux
**JavaScript:** V8 7.1.302.31
**Flash:**  (Desativada)
**Agente do usuário:**  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) snap Chromium/71.0.3578.98 Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
**Linha de comando:**   /snap/chromium/562/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --password-store=basic --ppapi-flash-path --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
**Caminho do executável:**  /snap/chromium/562/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome
**Caminho de perfil:**  /home/wagner/snap/chromium/562/.config/chromium/Default

the last line above is my PROFILE PATH

Pay attention on the last line which you need to point to your profile path. You need to set the ExperimentalOption to false as well. I set my ChromeOptions like this:

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        **options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);**
        **options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/home/wagner/snap/chromium/562/.config/
chromium/Default");**

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing helped out of the methods above.

`sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver` helped. This makes some link to snap.

Also, when installing from snap it is better to also run `sudo apt install chromium-browser`, because snap does not create *chromium-browser* link. 
Note that it write that the browser version is 80, but 81 is installed from snap.

Comment: me hercules! this was it

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by not completely deleted Chrome/Chromium. I faced this issue when tried to launch Jupyter Notebook after reinstalling Chromium. In similar case next steps may help^

```
# Show all .desktop entries of Chrome/Chromium
find ~ -name "*chrom*.desktop"

# Delete them
find ~ -name "*chrom*.desktop" | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to resolve this issue:
1. run this command to find all chrome*.desktop files.
    $ sudo find ~ -name "*chrome*.desktop"

the output in my computer:

> /home/thachhoangn/.gnome/apps/chrome-apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf-Profile_1.desktop 
>   /home/thachhoangn/.gnome/apps/chrome-blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo-Profile_1.desktop 
>   /home/thachhoangn/.gnome/apps/chrome-aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake-Profile_1.desktop 
>   /home/thachhoangn/.gnome/apps/chrome-pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia-Profile_1.desktop
>   /home/thachhoangn/.gnome/apps/chrome-fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop-Profile_1.desktop
>   /home/thachhoangn/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
>   /home/thachhoangn/.local/share/applications/chrome-apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf-Profile_1.desktop
>   /home/thachhoangn/.local/share/applications/chrome-blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo-Profile_1.desktop
>   /home/thachhoangn/.local/share/applications/chrome-aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake-Profile_1.desktop
>   /home/thachhoangn/.local/share/applications/chrome-pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia-Profile_1.desktop
>   /home/thachhoangn/.local/share/applications/chrome-fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop-Profile_1.desktop

As you see, those chrome*.desktop files are located in 2 directories. 
/home/thachhoangn/.gnome/apps/ and /home/thachhoangn/.local/share/applications/

Now, list all files in these directories and take a look on the modified date time of files:

> thachhoangn@thachhoangn ~ $ ll /home/thachhoangn/.gnome/apps/ 
>   total 32 
>   drwx------ 2 thachhoangn thachhoangn 4096 Nov 15 01:14 ./ 
>   drwx------ 3 thachhoangn thachhoangn 4096 Jul 26 16:22 ../
>   -rw------- 1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  344 Oct  8 09:36 chrome-aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake-Profile_1.desktop
>   -rw------- 1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  352 Oct 17 07:34 chrome-apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf-Profile_1.desktop
>   -rw------- 1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  347 Oct  8 09:36 chrome-blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo-Profile_1.desktop
>   -rw------- 1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  332 Nov 15 01:14 chrome-fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop-Profile_1.desktop
>   -rw------- 1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  345 Oct  8 09:36 chrome-pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia-Profile_1.desktop
>   -rw------- 1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  325 Jul 30 12:03 jetbrains-pycharm.desktop
>   
>   thachhoangn@thachhoangn ~ $ ll /home/thachhoangn/.local/share/applications/
>   total 112
>   drwx------  2 thachhoangn thachhoangn 4096 Dec 12 09:51 ./
>   drwx------ 20 thachhoangn thachhoangn 4096 Dec 11 19:32 ../
>   -rw-------  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  328 Oct  8 09:36 chrome-aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake-Profile_1.desktop
>   -rw-------  1 unifiedqe4 unifiedqe4  981 Dec 11 16:03 google-chrome.desktop
>   -rw-------  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  336 Oct 17 07:34 chrome-apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf-Profile_1.desktop
>   -rw-------  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  331 Oct  8 09:36 chrome-blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo-Profile_1.desktop
>   -rw-------  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  316 Nov 15 01:14 chrome-fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop-Profile_1.desktop
>   -rw-------  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  329 Oct  8 09:36 chrome-pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia-Profile_1.desktop
>   -rw-------  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  309 Jul 30 12:03 jetbrains-pycharm.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  283 Dec 11 16:03 mimeapps.list
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  813 Nov 15 09:34 mimeinfo.cache
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  311 Nov 12 15:36 wine.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  213 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-chm.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  220 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-gif.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  215 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-hlp.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  213 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-htm.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  227 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-ini.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  223 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-jfif.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  222 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-jpe.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  236 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-msp.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  247 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-ndm.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  218 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-pdf.desktopv
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  220 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-png.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  210 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-rtf.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  205 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-txt.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  228 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-url.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  218 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-vbs.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  216 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-wri.desktop
>   -rw-rw-r--  1 thachhoangn thachhoangn  218 Nov 15 09:34 wine-extension-xml.desktop

Based on modified datetime, you can try to delete one of those files that recently edited. Each time deleted a file, open chrome to check if the issue is gone. 
I deleted 2 files : chrome.desktop, google-chrome.desktop which modified recently and it resolves the issue.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue in my UBUNTU 18 OS this way, after I looked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075103/chromium-config-folder-is-missing-in-ubuntu-18-04):

1) I uninstalled chromium by writing in the terminal-

```
snap remove chromium
```

2) I installed "Chromium Web Browser" instead. Then it simply worked!

Details:
It seems i didn't have a ~/.config/google-chrome/ directory. as chromium was a snap version. it was probably not supported by the ChromeDriver. cleaning the snap version and going to "Chromium Web Browser" made the magic work.

Answer (score 0):

Procceed as follows:

- Open the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
- Type `nautilus`.
- Go to the folder `opt`.
- Find the folder named `google` and rename it to `google_old`.
- Restart your system.
- Install Chrome again.

That should resolve your issue.