# Chromium config folder is missing in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: chromium

I've installed Chromium from the Ubuntu Software app and added extensions such as lastpass and authy. Lastpass wasn't remembering my browser, and upon investigating I discovered I don't have Chromium config files where I should expect them. I've checked:

`~/.config/google-chrome`

`~/.config/chromium`

Is there a way I can set this or find out where they are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you installed the browser from the Software Center, you need to know there are two possibilities:

[image: Two versions of the browser]

The one named "Chromium" is what is known as a snap version and you can read more about snaps [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/761290/248158).

[image: The snap version]

Notice the source is the **Snap Store** and the download size is 141.6 MB.

The one listed as "Chromium Web Browser" is the regular version, like most of your other software, from the repositories.

[image: the regular version]

The source is the universe repository and its size is only 57 MB.

(By convention, if both a snap and a regular version are available for the same application, the snap version is listed above the regular version. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-remove.html.en).)

Your browser profile in the case of the second version, the regular version, will be in `~/.config/chromium` as you pointed out in your question.

With the snap version, things are different. Snaps you install as a user will be in your home folder in the `snap` subfolder.

To find your profile folder for the snap version, point your file manager or terminal to `~/snap/chromium/471/.config/chromium`.

Given the nature of snaps, you may find your experience a bit restricted in interacting with the rest of your system.

If you have indeed installed the snap version and wish to remove it, make sure it isn't running, open a terminal and execute `snap remove chromium`. You'll get an interface asking you for your password. Provide it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Done. Keep in mind that everything in `~/snap/chromium`, including your profile data, will be removed!

Comment: For me, on Ubuntu 20.04, seems running `chromium` or `chriomium-browser`, ends into the same: the snap version.

Answer (score 3):

Latest version of chromium are snap package.

I found profile in `~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default/`

Comment: Any idea why snap introduces so much problems?

Answer (score 0):

A Chromium have their own mechanism of storing passwords, what can have a meaning also that such extensions are extremely dangerous for using with Chromium. This simply sounds reasonably. So okay, if you really want to share your Logins Store with these apps, you should to see into Chromium documentation around how to [run Chromium with flags](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)

So, be careful …